# VS Debug Visualizer for WP7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, windows-phone-7, debuggervisualizer

Does Visual Studio 2010 support Debug Visualizers for Windows Phone (Silverlight) development?

My visualizer works fine in Windows apps but simply won't show up when debugging WP7 apps (no error message either).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSDN Visualizers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx) look at the Note and remember that silverlight in WP7 runs in partial trusted mode.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you mean, you can use the shortcut ctrl+f9 to get access to the visualizer :)

Comment: I meant that my custom visualizer is not shown in the visualizer drop down list.

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry. I didn't get it.
I am not sure if I can help you then. I wish you good luck  :)